# Gac Multiple Projects From Visual Studio

Tags: c#, gac, com+, visual-studio-addins

We currently have "gacutil /i $(TargetPath)" as an external tool in visual studio and it works fine for gac'n a single project.

I want to be able to select multiple projects and gac them so I put together a batch script to test.

```
set randomfile=%random%

echo %1 %2 %3 > %randomfile%

gacutil.exe /f /il %randomfile%
```

When I test it from the command line it looks like it should work.  Then when I hook it up as "MultiGac.bat $(TargetPath)" and select multiple projects and try it don't work.

Has anybody written any tools to accomplish such as tast either with a AddIn or external tool?  How about using regsvcs as well?

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Can the file be found but it just doesn't do the install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to write an Add In that scanned all projects an gac'd and reg'd them.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables inside batch files should use double % as prefix:

```
for %%i in (*.dll) do gacutil.exe /f /il %%i
```